# Android edittext onEditorActionListener working wrong?

Tags: android

I have a listview with edittext. EditText is set on editor action listener. it's work fine at 1st. But when I press Done key on the keyboard and I want to edit the former row of the listview, edittext does not take the new value.
How can I fix this problem?
Tks guys ^^

```
holder.zaiko_no.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                String zk = holder.zaiko_no.getText().toString();
                holder.item.setZaikoNo(zk);
                int zaiko_no_length = zk.length();
                int shelf_num_length = holder.shelf_num.getText().toString().length();
                if (position == n - 1) {
                    if (zaiko_no_length > 0 && shelf_num_length > 0) {
                        ShelfActivity.shelfItemList.add(new ShelfItem());
                    }
                }
                if (zaiko_no_length > 0 && shelf_num_length > 0) {
                    holder.status.setText("-");
                    holder.item.setStatus("-");
                    if(position == ShelfActivity.shelfItemList.size()-2){
                        sendBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.status.setText("");
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(sendCheck()) sendBtn.setEnabled(true);
                else sendBtn.setEnabled(false);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Time the view is created the edit text loses its data.Because of that you have to hold the data in some array.So create a String[] Array of size equal to the number of rows.

Initialize the String Array for holding the data --
String[] zaiko_no = new String()[list.size()];

inside setOnEditorActionListener --
zaiko_no[position] = holder.zaiko_no.getText().toString();

Outside the Listener--
 zaiko_no.setText(zaiko_no[position]);

Hope this helps.

Comment: tks guy. I found the solution :D I made textView final so that it cannot be editted :)))))) tks ^^